# Creating a tarball using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to create a tarball after a successful Jenkins build. I am new to this. So Wanted to find out if there is a plugin for this. Or I should be writing down a shell script from as a post build action in order to create this tarball.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ArtifactDeployer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin) but you should think why you create tarball shoud your send it to mail recipients publish somethere or something else.

Comment: I wrote a shell script for doing this and it builds the tar file now. I believe this plugin achieves the same task. Thanks for your help. :)