# how to use tar in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, tar

I have an error in my code. I've confirmed that the file definatley exists with ls

```
sh 'ls node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/'

CHANGELOG.md
CONTRIBUTING.md
LICENSE
README.md
bin
built
config.json
docs
gulpfile.js
package.json
```

Then I've tried to zip the directory but get this error:

```
sh 'tar -zxf selenium.tar.gz -C node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/'

tar (child): selenium.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

I have read a previous article explaining it maybe to do with setting the PATH variable in Jenkins. I am not sure how to do that or what I need to add and where?

- [Creating a tarball using Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248963/creating-a-tarball-using-jenkins)
- [Extract tar the tar.bz2 file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958741/extract-tar-the-tar-bz2-file-error)

I am using windows 10, and this is a dockerized version of jenkins.
Any advice welcome.
thanks

Comment: Hi @Steve you are extracting the tar file instead of creating. replace option 'x' with 'c'

Comment: sh 'tar -zcf selenium.tar.gz -C node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I've misunderstood my actions. The intention is wrong so the question can't be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a jenkinsFile you can use:

```
tar file: 'your-files.tar.gz', dir: 'your-files-dir'
```

More info in the documentation:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#tar-create-tar-file